# Not able to add product options (configurable product) into a separate tab

Tags: magento-1.9, php, configurable-product

I need to add product options (preference tab) to a new tab along Descrition, Additional, Tags, Review etc like in image.
[image]

I am using below xml layout in `<catalog_product_view>`.

```
<reference name="product.info.additional">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>product_tag_list</name></action>
        <block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs">
            <action method="setTemplate" ><template>catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ><alias>preferences_tabbed</alias><title>Preferences</title><block>catalog/product_view_options</block><template>catalog/product/view/preferences.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ><alias>description_tabbed</alias><title>Description</title><block>catalog/product_view_description</block><template>catalog/product/view/description.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ><alias>additional_tabbed</alias><title>Additional</title><block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block><template>catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="tag" ><alias>tags_tabbed</alias><title>Tags</title><block>tag/product_list</block><template>tag/list.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="review" ><alias>review_tabbed</alias><title>Reviews</title><block>review/product_view_list</block><template>review/product_info_review.phtml</template></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

`catalog/product/view/preferences.phtml` has this bunch of code copied from view.phtml. I know what it does.

```
<?php if ($this->getProduct()->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

I don't have idea how to declare container2 as child inside the Preferences tab.

Please help me if you have an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is now it can be solved,

It needed to add options block into `preferences_tabbed` reference in `catalog_product_view`.

```
<reference name="product.info.additional">
    <action method="unsetChild"><name>product_tag_list</name></action>
    <block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs">
        <action method="setTemplate" ><template>catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ><alias>preferences_tabbed</alias><title>Preferences</title><block>catalog/product_view_options</block><template>catalog/product/view/preferences.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ><alias>description_tabbed</alias><title>Description</title><block>catalog/product_view_description</block><template>catalog/product/view/description.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ><alias>additional_tabbed</alias><title>Additional</title><block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block><template>catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="tag" ><alias>tags_tabbed</alias><title>Tags</title><block>tag/product_list</block><template>tag/list.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="review" ><alias>review_tabbed</alias><title>Reviews</title><block>review/product_view_list</block><template>review/product_info_review.phtml</template></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

In above xml there is block named/aliased `preferences_tabbed`. Now let's add options block.

```
<reference name="preferences_tabbed">
    <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container2" as="container2">
        <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container2</value></action>
        <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
        <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
        <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

That's it. Now the configuration options will display in the Preferences tab.

NOTE: Please note, you might need to readjust the position `<form id="product_addtocart_form" ....` and it's closing tag to wrap whole `view.phtml` page.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="Your_attribute_name" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml"> <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action> <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Your tab name</value></action> </block>
```

or

Try this Extension free extension

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/free-products-tabs-extension-for-magento.html

Comment: #Kothari thanks, but this isn't the solution I am looking for. I already have the attributes into the tab (Additional). I want to add configuration options like (select menu of size/color etc) into above image tab Preferences.